# Как задавать лейбл префабу программно в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли возможность задавать каждому префабу лейбл программно и если есть, то как это можно сделать ?

Comment: .name не подходит?

Comment: Для чего это нужно? и что вы имеете в виду под лейблом?

Comment: Задача заключается в том, что необходимо разработать конфигуратор. Конфигуратор позволяет пользователю сопоставить контент метке. Для того что бы этот контент можно было передать на сервер, его нужно упаковать в AssetBundle. Для этого, этому контенту требуется дать лейбл(под лейблем я понимаю название AssetBundle’а).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAAaoRW6dSn5lR8z4lJyN27yOXfdp1TTqBU